# C# WebClient Download Time Left

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I'm trying to display a Time Left Label in my C# download form which is similar to that of browsers like chrome. I've already tried the following based of a java answer to the same issue on stack overflow but it's really unstable: Goes to negatives, hours go up and down fast same for the minutes etc.

```
var elapsedTime = DateTime.Now.Second - _startTime.Second;
var allTimeFordownloading = (elapsedTime * e.TotalBytesToReceive / e.BytesReceived);
var remainingTime = allTimeFordownloading - elapsedTime;
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(remainingTime);
TimeRemaining.Text = string.Format("Time Remaining: {0} Minutes, {1} Seconds", time.Minutes, time.Seconds);

Progress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
DownloadPercentage.Text = string.Format("{0}/100%", e.ProgressPercentage);
if (e.BytesReceived < 1024)
     BytesLeft.Text = string.Format("{0}/{1} KBs", Math.Round(e.BytesReceived / 1024f), Math.Round(e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024f));
 else
     BytesLeft.Text = string.Format("{0}/{1} MBs", (Math.Round((e.BytesReceived / 1024f) / 1024f)), Math.Round((e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024f) / 1024f));
```

_startTime is a DateTime started before the DownloadFileAsync method is called. Progress is the name of the ProgressBar on my form and e is the DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs object passed to the event handler.

Edit:
My question is the best way to calculate remaining time on a C# WebClient download?

Comment: see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadprogresschanged(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: We'll answer your question if you can answer this one:  When I drive my car it looks blue.

Answer (score 1):

```
var elapsedTime = DateTime.Now.Second - _startTime.Second;
```

[`DateTime.Second`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.second%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) only returns the seconds component, expressed as a value between 0 and 59. This can lead to highly unexpected behaviour, as a 63-second delay would be treated as if it only lasted 3 seconds (modulo 60).

You need to be careful to work with full time components. For example, you can use `TimeSpan.TotalSeconds`:

```
var elapsedTime = (DateTime.Now - _startTime).TotalSeconds;
```

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh: No. `TotalMilliseconds` would work, but it doesn't really make a difference since `TotalSeconds` is `double` and gives the same precision.